# how to delete a system partition

Tags: windows, partitioning

I tried searching hours without any success. I have a multi-boot machine (a laptop) with Win 8, Win 7, Ubuntu, Linux Mint, and OpenSuse installed. Around 2 years ago, the first OS I installed was Win 8, so during the Windows installation my C: partition has been marked as "primary", "active", and "boot". Right now, the order of my partitions is like this:

- Win 8 (Win 8 recognizes this partition as C:, but Win 7 recognizes it as C:),
- Win 7 (recognized as C: in Win 7, but as D: in Win 8),
- four ext4 partitions (3 Linux distros + 1 swap partition), and
- two other NTFS partitions (containing data).

Yesterday, I made my Win 7 partition "primary" and "active" as well. And then tried to make it "bootable" using EasyBCD 2.2. This app managed to do so, but with a failure and messing up my filesystem. I spent the last night to check (Win 7 and Win 8) partitions for errors using the Checkdisk command (to remove the orphan entries, rebuild the index, and so on) (booted using the Windows 7 installation disk and used the repair console). And after that, I used the commands `bootrec /fixmbr`, `bootrec /fixboot`, and `bootrec /rebuildbcd`. After recovering the Windows bootloader, I booted to my Linux Mint live USB, and restored and overwrote Grub to MBR and appended Windows chainloader to it.

Now, I want to delete/format the Win 8 and its partition totally (to free up some space) and to append its space to my Win 7 partition. I tried to use Disk Management Console couple of times, but since the Win 8 partition is still a system partition (and primary), it refuses to delete it. My efforts to format this partition failed as well. I also used EaseUS Partition Master 9.3 and AOMEI Partition Assistant Pro 5.1 without any success.

Any suggestion?

By the way, (after removing the Win 8 partition) I'm also looking for a way to assign part of the freed space to those 2 other NTFS partitions at the end of my HDD (I assume this positioning (of partitions) is rather logical, right?). So, my second question is:

How can I move those NTFS partitions to next to Win 7 partition and assign the free space to (one of) them.

Here is the layout of my disk:

[image]

Comment: We need the layout of the disk itself.  if the Windows 8 is at the start of the disk you won't be able to expand the partitions at the end of the disk

Answer (score -1):

Since nobody answered and I was in a hurry, after ruining my boot loader again (by formatting Win 8 partition (using the Win 7 installation DVD), and copying boot directory and bootmgr from Win 7 partition to it), I realized that since the Win 8 partition is the first partition, there is no way to get rid of it except formatting it and installing a new Win 7 on that partition. So, I did so, and then rebuilt the BCD and fixed the MBR using Win 7 installation DVD.

Comment: Not, in fact true.  It's nothing to do with it being the _first_ partition; and far from there being "no way" there were at least two other approaches (such as redesignating the second partition as the system partition).

Comment: @JdeBP could you explain so that other people would be saved from the same trouble I had?

Comment: By the way, after doing the above mentioned actions, I got into another trouble with deleting the old system partition (Win 7 partition/D:), so I had to delete both partitions (with lots of software installed and configured on the old Win 7), and had to create a new partition using the space freed up. Wasted 2 days! Save the others from this chaos with your answer, if you can.